# Fedora 26 won't show thumbnails for image and media files on network drives

Tags: linux, fedora, network-shares, thumbnails

I've just installed Fedora 26 on my laptop and everything works perfectly fine, just as expected, except one thing: thumbnails for images, videos and and audio files don't show up on network drives. The preferences of Nautilus are set to show thumbnails for all files smaller than 4 GB, which usually does the trick, and it does work for PDF files, but for anything else, thumbnails just won't show up.

I have already tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-image-thumbnails always
```

just in case the Nautilus preferences are being stupid (even though it's obviously already working for PDFs) - no success.

Is there anything I'm missing?